# How do I create a new object in java that has the properties of another one without declaring it?

Tags: java

For example, I have a JButton with a set icon, name and label;
How do I make a new JButton that I can add, say, to a panel?

```
JButton b1=new JButton();
b1.set[whatever needs to be set];
JPanel p=new JPanel();
p.add(new JButton()[that has the properties of b1]);
```

Comment: You want to create an object without instantiating it? Doesn't make sense, please be more clear about what you are trying to do. Do you want to clone the button?

Comment: Clone, see http://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/cloning/a-guide-to-object-cloning-in-java/

Comment: You can create a class that extends `JButton`, and create a copy constructor.

Comment: I meant declaring not instantiating, but I think it was quite clear what I meant

Answer (score 1):

Using exactly the same properties? Then you can try `b1.clone()`. In your case it will be `p.add(b1.clone());`. `clone()` can create a shallow copy of your object, see [clone()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()). And check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java) for copying.